# QGIS Rasterize tree polygons - giving priority to higher trees

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, rasterization

I used points of trees and created buffers around them based on their canopy widths. I rasterized these polygons and burned tree height as a value (later to be used for shadow modeling).
Important is to add that many trees overlap since their crowns are touching.

[image]

After using the 'Rasterize' (gdal) tool I got a raster where most of the lower trees got priority over higher ones and it seems that they 'cover' higher trees.

[image]

To fix it, I tried [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322906/overlapping-polygons-layer-order) approach, and it fixed some of the conflicts (lower tree over higher), but not all of them. I also tried dissolving trees based on the same height and then rasterizing, but it didn't work.

Is there any other approach to give priority to polygons with higher Tree-height value and obtain spatially more accurate raster?

Comment: In 2016 I asked here similar question - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206120/get-minimum-maximum-average-mean-with-gdal-rasterize. In your particular case you might try option -sql with select all and order by height - I do not know if gdal rasterize supports order by but worth a shot. If that is not possible you will have to process your vector layer first - cut all polygons by intersections, and filter overlaps to highest.

Comment: What expression did you use in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322906/overlapping-polygons-layer-order) approach? `id` or `tree-height`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it with this procedure:

1. Intersect - creates the intersections of polygons and adds them as rows to the attribute table, also creates a new field with the value of each polygon separated by '|' sign.
2. Create a new ID field in previously created Intersect layer with $id in Field Calculator.
3. Export Intersect layer to csv and open it in Excel.
4. Separate the column by delimiter '|' (Data - Text to columns).
5. Find the max value within new columns (Formulas - AutoSum - Max).
6. Upload the table to QGIS and join the table to Intersect layer with new ID field as a unique identifier.
7. Result of 'Rasterize' is below.

[image]